# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, php7, oracle-12c

Estoy intentando conectar a una base de datos Oracle mi aplicación PHP (7.3), pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

El código es este:

```
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'server/database');
```

En el fichero `php.ini` he descomentado las líneas:

```
extension=oci8_12c
extension=pdo_oci
```

También he instalado Instant Client Basic Package e Instant Client ODBC Package.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que esté la extensión cargada cuando haces un `phpinfo()`? ¿Has reiniciado el servidor apache tras modificar el `php.ini`? Si estás en windows y usas una DLL entonces no olvides agregar la extensión de archivo `.dll`: `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll` y `extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia no se están cargando las extensiones en `phpinfo()`, solamente aparecen en `PHP Credits`. El servidor sí lo he reiniciado, y sí, es un Windows, no había añadido la extensión del archivo ya que no la tenía añadida en ninguna extensión, pero la he añadido y tampoco funciona.

Comment: ¿De dónde has obtenido los archivos DLL? Existen dos tipos de extensiones para PHP para Windows dependiendo de si han sido compilados en modo seguro multihilo (**ts**) o no (**nts**). Además, también tienes que comprobar que sea la misma arquitectura (32 o 64 bits). Posteriormente debes poner el nombre exacto que tenga el archivo DLL (o renombrarlo). También vendría ver el mensaje de error que te está saliendo en el archivo `error.log` que te está generando el servidor al fallar la carga de las extensiones.

Comment: @OscarGarcia los DLL venían con la instalación de XAMPP, he usado los que llevaba por defecto. El nombre es exáctamente el mismo.

Comment: ¿Qué te sale en el archivo del log de error del servidor? Es probable que el motivo por el que no carga la extensión esté saliendo allí.

Comment: @OscarGarcia me sale este error en el log `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\oci8_12c (No se puede encontrar el m\xef\xbf\xbddulo especificado.), C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_oci8_12c.dll (No se puede encontrar el m\xef\xbf\xbddulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: ¿Podrías mirar cuál es el nombre que tiene en `C:\xampp\php\ext\`? Como te dije, debe escribirse exactamente tal y como esté la DLL en ese directorio. Por otro lado me dijiste que no has descargado la DLL de ningún sitio, que estás usando XAMPP, pero creo que por temas de la licencia de Oracle XAMPP no puede distribuir esas DLLs... así que es muy probable que en ese directorio no estén las DLLs que necesitas. Tendrás que descargarlas de la web de Oracle.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109098/discussion-between-angogi-and-oscargarcia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los pasos para resolver este problema han sido:

1. Comprobar que la arquitectura de PHP y de Instant Client era la misma.
2. Descomentar en `php.ini` las líneas `extension=oci8_12c` y `extension=pdo_oci`.
3. Volver a descargar el archivo DLL desde PECL (https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.2.0/windows).
4. Descomprimir en la misma carpeta tanto [Instant Client Basic como Instant Client ODBC](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html).
5. Añadir la ruta donde se ha descomprimido Instant Client al `PATH`.
6. Reiniciar el servidor.

Tras estos pasos funcionaba correctamente.